# Digital Forensic test image?

Tags: forensics

Does anyone know where I can get a free forensic test image for FTK? I need it to be below 5000 files for the demo. I found one but it is larger than 5k and it spits errors back at me.

Comment: For those of us who aren't familiar with FTK, care to provide a bit more detail?

Comment: this is what I use for testing, you might find one here: http://dftt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe look for floppy disk images. Such as this one: http://project.honeynet.org/scans/scan24/

Answer (score 2):

After a few minutes of Google searching, I found the following site that has two different images < 5000 files. One is a floppy disk and the other is a very small hard drive

http://myweb.cwpost.liu.edu/cmalinow/csi/tools.html

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit after the fact given the date of the original post, but you could always download FTK Imager or ProDiscover Basic from TechPathways.com.  These allow you to convert and split the images into several smaller, acceptable images.  Then you get all the files.  You'll just have to examine them individually.  But, hey...it all lends itself to good practice, right?